# HDRI map - blue tint

Tags: hdri

I created an outdoor HDRI map to composite a model into a real life footage, unfortunately, because of the broad dynamic range, my HDRI appears REALLY blue [the sky part only]. Needless to say it doesn't match at all.
I added a hue/saturation node and desaturated the HDRI quite a bit, but is there any other way that you guys prevent that from happening?
I captured HDRI with Insta 360, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply the image used as environment with a blackbody to get the [Color Temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature#:%7E:text=Color%20temperature%20is%20conventionally%20expressed,warm%20colors%22%20(yellowish)). you want. If the image is too blue try a value that is less than 6500° K

E.g 6500°K:

[image]

4800°K

[image]

3200°K

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But the rest of the scene casts a good color, so for example trees around it or the ground - the only issue is the blue sky. 
I guess that's normal, then.

Comment: Yes, a blue sky will make the shadows blueish. That is what happens in real life, we just don't pay attention. If you dislike that, you can always do color correction in post to diminish the blue cast with a Hue correct node.

Comment: I'm not talking about shadows-  I'm talking about this vs this
https://imgur.com/a/kQbxWj0

Comment: and just to be clear - I know how temperature works, my shot is balanced for daylight as well as my HDRI, they should both match in temp. yet the sky gives it suck a blue tint it's insane.

Comment: @AciD please edit your original post and add the images you consider relevant to your question there.

Answer (score 0):

You should shoot hdris in RAW and set proper wite balance in any Lightroom program. You can tweak also final hdri file in Photoshop or Affinity Photo which offers white balance correction for 32-bit files.